# Not getting the auth errors of authenticationUtils in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, error-handling, symfony4

I have an issue with the Authentication Errors when login in my app in Symfony 4.
I can perfectly login with all users, but when I try to fail the login on purpose I don't get any error message neither the $error fills. Here I post the code of my LoginFormAuthenticator and my securityController.
**LoginFormAuthenticator**

```
    class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    /**
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    private $userRepository;
    /**
     * @var RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;
    /**
     * @var CsrfTokenManagerInterface
     */
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository, RouterInterface $router, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }
    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'app_login'
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'cargo' => $request->request->get('cargo'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];

        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['cargo']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }
        return $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['cargo' => $credentials['cargo']]);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        // todo
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_homepage'));
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        // todo
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        // todo
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->router->generate('app_login');
    }
}
```

**login function:**

```
/**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ]);
    }
```

**Login HTML twig**

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post">
        {% if error %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
            <h3>{{ error.messageKey }}</h3>
        {% endif %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just comment out your onAuthenticationFailure method and let the parent class deal with it.  If you do have the urge to write your own then check the parent code to see what is needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

The onAuthenticationFailure method is empty. See parent::onAuthenticationFailure.
Method should returns Response object.